# Postgres update trigger

Tags: postgresql

I've problem with a trigger function in postgresql.
Here my simple code.

```
CREATE TABLE specie
(specie_id INT PRIMARY KEY GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
nome_comune TEXT UNIQUE,
nome_scientifico TEXT UNIQUE);

CREATE TABLE rilevatore
(rilevatore_id INT PRIMARY KEY GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
nome_cognome TEXT);

CREATE TABLE evento_investimento
(evento_id INT PRIMARY KEY GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
data DATE,
ora TIME WITHOUT TIME ZONE,
rilevatore_id INT REFERENCES rilevatore (rilevatore_id),
specie_id INT REFERENCES specie(specie_id));

CREATE VIEW inserimento_dati_vista AS
SELECT row_number() OVER ()::integer AS gid,
evento_investimento.ora,
evento_investimento.data,
rilevatore.nome_cognome,
specie.nome_comune,
specie.nome_scientifico
FROM evento_investimento
JOIN specie ON evento_investimento.specie_id = specie.specie_id
JOIN rilevatore ON evento_investimento.rilevatore_id = rilevatore.rilevatore_id;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION inserimento_dati_fun_2() RETURNS trigger AS $$
BEGIN
if not exists(select * from rilevatore where rilevatore.nome_cognome=new.nome_cognome) then
INSERT INTO rilevatore (nome_cognome)
VALUES (NEW.nome_cognome);
end if;
if not exists(select * from specie where specie.nome_comune=new.nome_comune) then
INSERT INTO specie (nome_comune, nome_scientifico)
VALUES (NEW.nome_comune, NEW.nome_scientifico);
end if;
INSERT INTO evento_investimento (data, ora, rilevatore_id, specie_id)
VALUES (NEW.data,NEW.ora,
(SELECT rilevatore_id FROM rilevatore WHERE rilevatore.nome_cognome = NEW.nome_cognome),
(SELECT specie_id FROM specie WHERE specie.nome_comune = NEW.nome_comune));
RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

create trigger inserimento_dati_fun_trg 
    instead of insert on inserimento_dati_vista for each row EXECUTE procedure inserimento_dati_fun_2();
```

Now, I want to add a function that allow to update all the tables by using the view inserimento_dati_vista.

I've tried with a simple code to update only the data column

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_dati_fun_2() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
IF (TG_OP = 'UPDATE') THEN
IF old.data is distinct from new.data then
UPDATE evento_investimento
SET data = new.data;
END IF;
END IF;
RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

create trigger update_dati_fun_2_trg
        instead of update on inserimento_dati_vista for each row EXECUTE procedure update_dati_fun_2();
```

However when I perfomr the query in order to update only a row, the trigger update all the rows in the table. Here some code to fill data.

```
INSERT INTO inserimento_dati_vista
(data, ora, nome_cognome, nome_comune, nome_scientifico)
VALUES
('2020-01-01', '16:54:00','mario', 'lupo', 'Canis lupus'),
('2020-01-02', '13:54:00','luca', 'lontra', 'Lutra lutra');

UPDATE inserimento_dati_vista
SET data = '2021-01-02' where nome_cognome = 'luca'
```

Comment: Looks like you forgot a `WHERE` condition in your `UPDATE` statement.

Comment: Actually, when I run the UPDATE statement on pgadmin4 I receive the right message,
UPDATE 1
Query returned successfully in 37 msec.
However all the rows were updated.

Comment: I am talking about the `UPDATE` statement in the trigger. It is lacking a `WHERE` condition.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I modified the trigger with the where condition but nothing is changed

`CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_dati_fun_2() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
IF (TG_OP = 'UPDATE') THEN
IF old.data is distinct from new.data then
UPDATE evento_investimento
SET data = new.data where old.data <> new.data;
END IF;
END IF;
RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;`

Answer (score 0):

Update function is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_dati_fun_2() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
IF (TG_OP = 'UPDATE') THEN
IF old.data is distinct from new.data then
UPDATE evento_investimento e
    SET data = new.data
    FROM rilevatore r
    WHERE nome_cognome = new.nome_cognome AND r.rilevatore_id = e.rilevatore_id;
END IF;
END IF;
RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```